# Can you direct incoming port 80 traffic to two different boxes, depending on what resource is requested?

Tags: networking, email, webserver, webmail

Currently I host my website on one server, and my email on another.  My email server is a Zentyal box, running Zarafa.  I can access the webmail from inside the network by entering the server's IP into the URL bar.

My question is, how could I set it up so the url (http://example.com/webaccess) would point to my email server?

So far I haven't been able to find much information on the subject and I'm left wondering if it's even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Put up a website at "example.com/webaccess" and have the default web page auto-redirect the visitor to the host mail server's webmail URL.

Answer (score 1):

For this task you can use a **reverse proxy**. This is a proxy which is not installed between a web client and the Internet but between the Internet (or other network) and the destination web server. As such it can make accessible various servers under URLs by your choice. Some of the commonly used open source reverse proxies are:

### Apache with mod_proxy

Basically in `httpd.conf` you:

Load the needed modules:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

and (near the end of the file) define remote web servers publication rules:

```
ProxyPass /webaccess http://your.email.server.com/
ProxyPassReverse /webaccess http://your.email.server.com/
```

Tutorial: [Configure Apache as a reverse proxy](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_apache_as_a_reverse_proxy.html)
Documentation: [Apache Module mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

### NGINX revese proxy

See the documentation [NGINX Reverse Proxy](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

### Possible problems

Be aware of the fact that the web interface of our email server can have some URLs (or parts of it) hard-coded and as such it could be difficult to make it working on a different URL.

Answer (score -2):

You need to speak with the Support team running the email box.  The interface you want to develop is not as simple as you might think, and it is different for different software.  If you were using Exchange setting up Web Access is simple, but with this proprietary software the best answer you'll get is to talk to their Support.